# error con rank en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo ésta consulta en sql server:

```
 SELECT distinct(em.id_empleado), al.region, al.des_almacen, al.cadenaventa, em.des_empleado, em.cargo, em.pais, al.id_almacen, 
T1.ventas, T1.boletas, T1.unidades, T2.trafico,

 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T1.boletas DESC) AS RankByBoletas   

FROM dim.almacen as al, dim.empleado as em, 

( SELECT id_almacen, id_empleado, sum(unidades_ytd) as unidades, sum(documentos_ytd) as boletas, sum(venta_ytd) as ventas 
FROM fact.venta_comparada_empleado WHERE id_calendario between 20180101 AND 20180630 GROUP BY id_almacen, id_empleado ) T1 
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT id_almacen, sum(val_trafico_ytd) as trafico FROM fact.trafico_comparada 
WHERE id_calendario between 20180101 AND 20180630 GROUP BY id_almacen ) T2 
ON T1.id_almacen = T2.id_almacen 
WHERE T1.id_almacen = al.id_almacen AND T1.id_empleado = em.id_empleado AND al.canalventa like 'RETAIL' 

ORDER BY id_almacen, id_empleado
```

Necesito obtener el *ranking* según el número de unidades facturadas * boleta, lo que sería algo mas o menos:

```
 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (T1.unidades/T1.boletas) DESC) AS RankByUniXBoletas
```

Pero hay registros donde el `T1.boletas` es `0`; intento incorporar un case de `T1.boletas > 0` pero me da error, es decir:

```
 SELECT distinct(em.id_empleado), al.region, al.des_almacen, 
   al.cadenaventa, em.des_empleado, em.cargo, em.pais, al.id_almacen, 
    T1.ventas, T1.boletas, T1.unidades, T2.trafico,

 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T1.boletas DESC) AS RankByBoletas,

 case when T1.boletas > 0 then 

 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (T1.unidades/T1.boletas) DESC)    

 else '700000' end AS RankByUniXBoletas  

  FROM dim.almacen as al, dim.empleado as em, 

( SELECT id_almacen, id_empleado, sum(unidades_ytd) as unidades, sum(documentos_ytd) as boletas, sum(venta_ytd) as ventas 
FROM fact.venta_comparada_empleado WHERE id_calendario between 20180101 AND 20180630 GROUP BY id_almacen, id_empleado ) T1 
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT id_almacen, sum(val_trafico_ytd) as trafico FROM fact.trafico_comparada 
WHERE id_calendario between 20180101 AND 20180630 GROUP BY id_almacen ) T2 
ON T1.id_almacen = T2.id_almacen 
WHERE T1.id_almacen = al.id_almacen AND T1.id_empleado = em.id_empleado AND al.canalventa like 'RETAIL' 

ORDER BY id_almacen, id_empleado
```

Pero me da error:

```
  Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
   Error de división entre cero.
```

Comment: una forma sencilla de evitar ese problema es usar `NULLIF`: `T1.unidades/NULLIF(T1.boletas,0)`

Comment: Gracias @Lamak con eso resolví mi problema

Comment: @Lamak, debes escribir eso como una respuesta!